# XML Decoder in SWIFTUI

Tags: swift, xml, xcode, decoder

I have a XML decoder and I want to add a decoding of a date string from my XML file to it. Help write the code for this please.

**XML:**

```
<horo>
<date yesterday="10.05.2021" today="11.05.2021" tomorrow="12.05.2021" tomorrow02="13.05.2021"/>
<aries>
<yesterday> Всякий эксперимент по-своему рискован, но - не попробуешь не узнаешь. Примите меры пожарной безопасности, и - можете приступать, у вас получится. </yesterday>
<today> Постарайтесь удержать свои эмоции в узде. Сегодня они могут здорово вам помешать, ибо будут как никогда буйны. </today>
<tomorrow> Вы, пребывая в лучезарном настроении, внесете нотку непринужденности в общее напряжение сегодняшней ситуации. Реагировать на это могут по-разному. Некоторые искренне обрадуются, другие же, возможно, поспешат обвинить вас в саботировании рабочего процесса. </tomorrow>
<tomorrow02> Как известно, не попробуешь - не узнаешь. Сегодня это должно стать вашим девизом. </tomorrow02>
</aries>
```

*I can't write the decoder code for this line:*

date yesterday="10.05.2021" today="11.05.2021" tomorrow="12.05.2021" tomorrow02="13.05.2021"

**Decoder:**

```
import SwiftyXMLParser

enum Signs: CaseIterable {
    case aries
    case taurus
    case gemini
    case cancer
    case leo
    case virgo
    case libra
    case scorpio
    case sagittarius
    case capricorn
    case aquarius
    case pisces
}

enum Period: CaseIterable {
    case yesterday
    case today
    case tomorrow
    case tomorrow02
}


class HoroscopeDecoder {
    
    static let shared = HoroscopeDecoder()
    
    func run(completion: @escaping ([String]) -> Void) {
        let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://ignio.com/r/export/utf/xml/daily/com.xml")!)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if let data = data, let xmlString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                let xml = try! XML.parse(xmlString)
                if let today = xml["horo", "\(Signs.aries)", "\(Period.today)"].text,
                   let tomorrow = xml["horo", "\(Signs.aries)", "\(Period.tomorrow)"].text,
                   let tomorrow02 = xml["horo", "\(Signs.aries)", "\(Period.tomorrow02)"].text,
                   let yesterday = xml["horo", "\(Signs.aries)", "\(Period.yesterday)"].text {
                    completion([today, tomorrow, tomorrow02, yesterday])
                } else {
                    completion(["Error", "Error", "Error", "Error", "Error"])
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: "I can't write the decoder code", this is more of a statement than a question. Could you elaborate on why you can’t write the code, what part is it you can’t solve?

Comment: I explained that I could not add line 2 from the XML file. Where it says: data